# JQuery find a nested ul in an iframe with a class and replace it

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe with a nested unordered list inside. I want to find the nested ul that has a class of 'expanded' and change it to 'collapsed'.

```
<iframe id='Catalog'>
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul id='items'>
        <li><ul></ul></li>
        <li><ul class='expanded'></ul></li>
        <li><ul></ul></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

I have tried many things, but have not quite gotten it right.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to get:

```
$('iframe#Catalog')
            .contents()
            .find('ul#items li ul')
            .hasClass('expanded')
            .removeClass('expanded')
            .addClass('collapsed');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can select by class with `$('.expanded')` -- you don't need to use `hasClass()`. You also don't need that `contents()` call at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasClass` returns a boolean value, it doesn't filter the elements, you can use class selector instead.

```
$('#Catalog')
          .contents()
          .find('ul.expanded')
          .removeClass('expanded')
          .addClass('collapsed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is in the iframe or outside it?
If your code is outside the iframe, on the container page i think you can't access the html inside the iframe for security reasons.
If you move the code (if thats possible) to the iframe content then it should work.